# Django lookup table query

Tags: django, django-models

I'm quite the Django newb and having a hard time figuring this query out..

Models:

```
class JakAlgAlgorithms(models.Model):
    alg_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    alg_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    alg_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.alg_name
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'jak_alg_algorithms'

class JakAlgXref(models.Model):
    xref_alg = models.ForeignKey(JakAlgAlgorithms, related_name='jakalgxref_alg' ,null=True, blank=True)
    xref_parent = models.ForeignKey(JakAlgAlgorithms, related_name='jakalgxref_parent', null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'jak_alg_xref'
```

What I'm trying to do is return all the parents or children of an algorithm. This is where I've managed to get to..

```
    parents = JakAlgAlgorithms.objects.filter(jakalgxref_parent= algorithm.jakalgxref_alg.all())
```

However, I've realised that this won't work for multiple parents. How can I have filter take jakalgxref_parent equal to each value returned by algorithim.jakalgxref_alg.all()? Seems like I'm missing something simple :/

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you're trying. Just a shot in the dark, is `parents = JakAlgAlgorithms.objects.filter(jakalgxref_parent__in= algorithm.jakalgxref_alg.all())` what you're trying to achieve? Notice I've only added the __in clause to you filter...

Comment: You should put the answer as an actual answer and mark as answered to benefit other users during search

Comment: You should probably not reinvent the wheel with this type of thing. There's libraries like django-mptt (https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) that make tree relationships trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Posting my previous comment as an answer for future users.**

What you're looking for is this:

```
parents = JakAlgAlgorithms.objects.filter(jakalgxref_parent__in= algorithm.jakalgxref_alg.all())
```

Notice I've only added the `__in` clause to you filter..